# Deleted comments

Tags: discussion, comments

My comments on this question were deleted:

[Is it ok to avoid testing base classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291200/is-it-ok-to-avoid-testing-base-classes#comment603254_291200)

Why?

EDIT: Also deleted on this answer:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/291169/53014

What is going on? Why is there a need to censor and moderate these SE sites to such an extent? It's annoying.

I'm calling it a day. I've been a daily contributor to SO and have helped many people resolve their problems, but you've lost out on the small contribution I was going to continue to make.

And I'll make sure my opinion is clear about these sites to anyone I suspect may have had a use for them.

Comment: I didn't delete your comments, but you seem to be taking this a lot more seriously than you should. Comments are ephemeral, they are not supposed to stick around for ever, and yours had clearly outlived their purpose. I did another sweep, and removed all other obsolete comments (the responses to your deleted comments, for example).

Comment: As for the comments on the answer... [be nice](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199302/131956

Answer (score 6):

I deleted your comments on [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290941/how-to-work-with-programmer-with-different-preference-of-indentation-width/291169#291169). [Comments are ephemeral](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), they are not supposed to stick around for ever, and yours had clearly outlived their purpose. Also, comments are expected to meet our [guidelines for behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), including [being nice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).